# Convert decimal string to hex string without storing into interger

Tags: c++, stdstring

I have a string which has decimal value. I need to convert that to hexa decimal value. I know that the string need to be converted into integer first using stoi and then convert to hex using stringstream std::hex

```
std::string hexString(std::string decimalString)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    int val = std::stoi(decimalString);
    ss << std::hex << val;
    return ss.str();
}
```

Since I need string output, is there any way to convert directly without converting to integer first and then hex.

Comment: You know it is needed and ask about whether it is needed?

Comment: Not in the standard, you could invest your time in creating your own, but I think your function is more than fine if it serves your needs.

Comment: I don't think there is a simpler way than converting the string to a decimal number and converting the decimal number to hexadecimal. I'll wait for somebody to prove me wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, you can implement conversion directly on std::string, by manipulating string characters as digits. You'll have to implement multiplication and addition on such numbers though, and it will be way slower than letting CPU do it.

In general the efficient conversion between bases A and B by mapping is only possible in certain cases, the simplest being when B is a power of A (or A of B), for example if A=2 and B=4:

```
1101010010
 3 1 1 0 2
```

so 1101010010-base2 becomes 31102-base4, conversion is done by mapping pairs of base2 digits to base4 digits. Note that this is essentially the same, it's just the intermediated integer is now only 2 bits wide, but at least the width of the intermediate does not depend on the widths of the inputs.